# Can't access a Google Script API executable URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-script-api

I have a google script which I wanted to access externally on a asp.net MVC web app. I have already implemented google authentication through Google OAuth on that web app and it works perfectly.

I followed the instructions and associated my script project with the google cloud OAuth I use for authentication. I have enabled the Apps Script API in the GCP. I created a deployment for the script as a API executable but when I test the deployment (as in "Test Deployment") I always get a "404 not found". If I test the Library URL though I get all the code from my script but can't, for the life of me, run the actual function in my script project (which, for testing purposes, is just a "hello world").

I'm at my wits end and desperately needed some help because I really need this to work.

I've tried different URL's besides the one on "Test Deployment" since everywhere I see there's a different format for the URL. I've tried reducing my script to a simple "hello world", I've tried setting a doGet and a doPost function.

I have enabled App Scripts API in my GCP. I've set the deployment as accessible to every option (even though I can't even run it as a owner).